# Copy java classes with all dependency to other package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to copy some classes of Java to another package. I want to say that if this class has a connection to another class, then that class should be copied there as well. I use IntelliJ and know I can press `F5`, but this feature copies only one class without any other classes. Can it be done automatically in IntelliJ or other IDE/tool?

Comment: "_if this class has a connection to another class, then that class should be copied there as well_" <- that's a weird requirement. Does it include JDK classes as well? What about other libraries?

Comment: I got this task to separate some classes into a separate project, and these classes are to be used by other projects. The whole project has 150 classes and needs to be divided into 20 classes (no dependent classes)

Comment: I think there's a plugin for that. Search for "move with dependencies".

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7260-move-with-dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin doesn`t work with the latest versions of IntelliJ (2019.1.3). There's a gray side panel with an inscription and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: There is no ready tool in IntelliJ IDEA to move the class with all its dependencies, please follow the feature request created for it at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90607. Thanks

Comment: Like I said, I don't think that plug-in works for me. And is this option of moving with dependencies in some other IDE (Eclipse/Netbeans)?